# Facebook like plugin no longer working, alternative?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I noticed the Facebook like button plugin stopped working.  Does anyone know an alternative that's not graph API?

This iframe would generate a Facebook like button with a count of likes

```html
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://stackoverflow.com">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: That is just a URL. Why would that give you a link button?

Comment: @WizKid sorry, iframe src

Comment: Works fine for me, your code renders a like button, as expected.

Comment: @CBroe this is what I see, https://i.imgur.com/7wn8Xqn.png, do you see a button with a like count?

Comment: After I allow it through my privacy settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfh6Y.png

Comment: @CBroe wow thank you!  Which privacy settings did you update?  I'm assuming in chrome?